# How do I properly test a wordpress Cron job?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cron

### Simple Abandoned Cart

https://github.com/gregbast1994/msp-abandoned-cart

This plugin simply skims emails at checkout and saves the cart session data. Then we set a cron job to check if the session became an order, if not set another for tomorrow to email the user. Simple abandoned cart functionality.

I've checked the list of cron jobs and can see the 'await_order_for_cart_..' job. I've also dumped the $wp_filter to check if I can find my function connected to a hook anywhere. I've tried making the functions attached to the job static.

The job dumped looks like

```
 [1566572607] => Array
        (
            [await_order_for_cart_04ff0471d799d19b53034ef078a600d8] => Array
                (
                    [e0f32ed5d8b7b8d89f1d8f832df788f2] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => 
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                    [hash] => 04ff0471d799d19b53034ef078a600d8
                                    [item_count] => 1
                                    [customer_id] => aeac13344550563f2be4186690b44ef5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

First setup the first job to check if the session becomes an order.

```
public function get_data( $email = '' )
{
    ...
    $this->set_wait_for_order_cron();
}

public function set_wait_for_order_cron()
     /**
      * Creates a unique hook using cart hash, schedules a check on cart
      */
     {
         if( empty( $this->cart['hash'] ) ) return;

         $hook = 'await_order_for_cart_' . $this->cart['hash'];
         $this->hooks['before'] = $hook;

         $one_hour = time() + 30;
         if( ! wp_next_scheduled( $hook ) ){
            wp_schedule_single_event( $one_hour, $hook, $this->cart );
            add_action( $hook, array( $this, 'check_order_for_cart' ) );
         }
     }
```

I do not think the check_order_for_cart ever runs because I never see the 'email_customer_abandoned_cart_...' job.

```
public static function get_session( $customer_id )
     {
        $handler = new WC_Session_Handler();
        return $handler->get_session( $customer_id );
     }

public static function check_order_for_cart( $cart )
     {
        /**
         * Splits up the session cookie, uses the first part to grab the cart session
         * If session is false, that means the cart expired or was order.
         */
         $session = $this->get_session( $cart['customer_id'] );

         if( false !== $session ){
            $hook = 'email_customer_abandoned_cart_' . $cart['hash'];
            $this->hooks['after'] = $hook;

            wp_schedule_single_event( time() + DAY_IN_SECONDS, $hook, $cart );
            add_action( $hook, array( $this, 'email_customer_abandoned_cart' ) );
         }
         // kill action
         remove_action( $this->hooks['before'], array( $this, 'check_order_for_cart' ) );
     }
```

Well, I expect that after the first job runs, the second job is created and in the cron queue. I expect when that second job runs that my email is sent and my customer comes back and buys lots of dildo's from me.

Comment: There is a plugin that will do this for you. Check out WP Crontol https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/